# Where to find PHP version usage stats?

Tags: php

My original question was: what percentage of sites are using php 5.4.x? (As it has [some very interesting new features](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).) With secondary questions like how many of the cheap web hosting places have upgraded, which versions of the linux distros include it, etc.

But I'm coming up blanks.
http://php.net/usage.php stops at July 2007, and the nexen.net website seems to have stopped in 2008. At SecuritySpace they only list the web servers, not php versions. The TIOBE link isn't what I'm after (it doesn't -- and couldn't -- break down by version number).

I thought php.net might show download numbers, but I cannot see them anywhere.

I kind of answered the distro question, but it requires a lot of clicking around at distrowatch.com. E.g. I see [here](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu) that Ubuntu offers php 5.4.6 in the latest snapshot, but the latest release (Ubuntu 12.04) has 5.3.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may find http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5/all of interest.  As far as your secondary question that's a little harder to answer.  With any new version of a language, the transition is slow.  As you can see from this website, 5.2 is more widely used than any other version of PHP5.  This is typical because of the resources required to check existing code against a new version.  It often seems "cheaper" to leave the code alone until you're forced to make the transition (support for the language version ceases).  For example Python recently announced that support for Python2 will be ceasing so we can probably expect to see a massive exodus from version 2 to version 3 over the next several months/years.

Comment: Excellent link thanks. (Also clicking through it shows which sites use php 5.4). The other technologies they analyze are also very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Version stats for PHP and MySQL used to run Wordpress.
http://wordpress.org/about/stats/

Comment: The latest version of Wordpress requires version 5.2.4

Comment: Interesting: 70% still on php 5.2! But 70% of what is not explained, beyond "WordPress users"; i.e. no explanation of their methodology, or even when the sample was taken. (OTOH they have 0.5% for php 5.4, so it must be taken some time this year.)

Comment: Given that the stats are on the wordpress website I would be willing to bet that the "of" is of wordpress instances.  I'd also be willing to bet that this is kept fairly up to date.  But keep in mind that this is in no way an accurate representation of the overall population given that it targets a very specific set of users.

Comment: The charts include Wordpress 3.4 which was released June 13, 2012. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions

Comment: @DarrenCook: The stats are collected twice-daily when sites running WP call home to check if a new version of WP was released. It's a daily snapshot of their install base for all intents and purposes.